Database slow performance after restoring dump from mariadb 10.4.22 to 11.2.4, ANALYZE TABLE command doesn't work
I'm running moodle on one of my two servers, he has moodle's DB on mariadb 10.4.22 and its under maintenance so i tranfered moodle to the other server that has mariadb 11.2.4, however the second server is having problems with moodle's DB performance, i have found a thread on moodle's foruns talking about problems with DB dump from 10.4.2 mariadb restored to a post 11 version, there its said that i need to run ANALYZE TABLE on the DB to make it work better:
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=446712
I tried this command on each table on the DB, however it didn't work and the DB still very slow (principally messages), i tried restoring the dump to the old server and it work normally, however moodle doesn't support mariadb 10.4.2 anymore so i will have to update, what can i do? Is there another command i can run? How can i troubleshoot the problem?(i'm not very experienced with troubleshooting so if you guys want some informationg just say that i will provide because i don't know what information is needed to solve this problem)
there is the results when i run mysqltuner on the new server(the one with mariadb 11.2.4) but it does not seems to help much.
mysqltuner1
mysqltuner2
mysqltuner3
mysqltuner4
EDIT: I've got a return from my slowlog
# Time: 240828 12:55:04
# User@Host: user[user] @ localhost []
# Thread_id: 318  Schema: my_db  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 332.625304  Lock_time: 0.000335  Rows_sent: 32  Rows_examined: 111342578
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 0
use my_db;
SET timestamp=1724849704;
SELECT m.id as messageid, mc.id as id, mc.name as conversationname, mc.type as conversationtype, m.useridfrom,
                   m.smallmessage, m.fullmessage, m.fullmessageformat, m.fullmessagetrust, m.fullmessagehtml, m.timecreated,
                   mc.component, mc.itemtype, mc.itemid, mc.contextid, mca.action as ismuted
              FROM ehvp_message_conversations mc
        INNER JOIN ehvp_message_conversation_members mcm
                ON (mcm.conversationid = mc.id AND mcm.userid = '21')
        LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT m.conversationid, MAX(m.id) AS messageid
                        FROM ehvp_messages m
                  INNER JOIN (
                                  SELECT m.conversationid, MAX(m.timecreated) as maxtime
                                    FROM ehvp_messages m
                              INNER JOIN ehvp_message_conversation_members mcm
                                      ON mcm.conversationid = m.conversationid
                               LEFT JOIN ehvp_message_user_actions mua
                                      ON (mua.messageid = m.id AND mua.userid = '21' AND mua.action = '2')
                                   WHERE mua.id is NULL
                                     AND mcm.userid = '21'
                                GROUP BY m.conversationid
                             ) maxmessage
                           ON maxmessage.maxtime = m.timecreated AND maxmessage.conversationid = m.conversationid
                     GROUP BY m.conversationid
                   ) lastmessage
                ON lastmessage.conversationid = mc.id
        LEFT JOIN ehvp_messages m
               ON m.id = lastmessage.messageid
        LEFT JOIN ehvp_message_conversation_actions mca
               ON (mca.conversationid = mc.id AND mca.userid = '21' AND mca.action = '1')
            WHERE mc.id IS NOT NULL
              AND mc.enabled = 1  AND (mc.type = '1' OR mc.type = '3')   AND mc.id <> '13'
          ORDER BY (CASE WHEN m.timecreated IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC, m.timecreated DESC, id DESC LIMIT 0, 51;

EDIT 2: I user the command EXPLAIN on the query on both servers:
The 11.2.4 mariadb server (the one suffering from perfomance issues, database is called my_db here):
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type     | table      | type       | possible_keys                                                                    | key                                               | key_len | ref                                        | rows    | Extra                                        |
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY         | mcm        | ref        | ehvp_messconvmemb_con_ix,ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix                                | ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix                          | 8       | const                                      | 4092    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | mc         | eq_ref     | PRIMARY,ehvp_messconv_typ_ix                                                     | PRIMARY                                           | 8       | my_db.mcm.conversationid                   | 1       | Using where                                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived2> | ref        | key0                                                                             | key0                                              | 9       | my_db.mcm.conversationid                   | 1       |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | m          | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                                                          | PRIMARY                                           | 8       | lastmessage.messageid                      | 1       | Using where                                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | mca        | ref|filter | ehvp_messconvacti_use_ix,ehvp_messconvacti_con_ix                                | ehvp_messconvacti_con_ix|ehvp_messconvacti_use_ix | 8|8     | my_db.mcm.conversationid                   | 1 (11%) | Using where; Using rowid filter              |
|    2 | LATERAL DERIVED | m          | ref        | ehvp_mess_contim_ix,ehvp_mess_con_ix                                             | ehvp_mess_contim_ix                               | 8       | my_db.mcm.conversationid                   | 2       | Using where; Using index                     |
|    2 | LATERAL DERIVED | <derived3> | ref        | key0                                                                             | key0                                              | 17      | my_db.m.conversationid,my_db.m.timecreated | 1       |                                              |
|    3 | DERIVED         | m          | index      | ehvp_mess_contim_ix,ehvp_mess_con_ix                                             | ehvp_mess_contim_ix                               | 16      | NULL                                       | 9664    | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    3 | DERIVED         | mua        | eq_ref     | ehvp_messuseracti_usemesac_uix,ehvp_messuseracti_use_ix,ehvp_messuseracti_mes_ix | ehvp_messuseracti_usemesac_uix                    | 24      | const,my_db.m.id,const                     | 1       | Using where; Using index; Not exists         |
|    3 | DERIVED         | mcm        | ref        | ehvp_messconvmemb_con_ix,ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix                                | ehvp_messconvmemb_con_ix                          | 8       | my_db.m.conversationid                     | 1       | Using where                                  |
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+

The 10.4.2 mariadb server (the one without issues, database is called moodle here):
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type     | table      | type       | possible_keys                                                                    | key                                               | key_len | ref                                          | rows    | Extra                                        |
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY         | mcm        | ref        | ehvp_messconvmemb_con_ix,ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix                                | ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix                          | 8       | const                                        | 2988    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | mc         | eq_ref     | PRIMARY,ehvp_messconv_typ_ix                                                     | PRIMARY                                           | 8       | moodle.mcm.conversationid                    | 1       | Using where                                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | <derived2> | ref        | key0                                                                             | key0                                              | 9       | moodle.mcm.conversationid                    | 2       |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | m          | eq_ref     | PRIMARY                                                                          | PRIMARY                                           | 8       | lastmessage.messageid                        | 1       | Using where                                  |
|    1 | PRIMARY         | mca        | ref|filter | ehvp_messconvacti_use_ix,ehvp_messconvacti_con_ix                                | ehvp_messconvacti_con_ix|ehvp_messconvacti_use_ix | 8|8     | moodle.mcm.conversationid                    | 1 (11%) | Using where; Using rowid filter              |
|    2 | LATERAL DERIVED | m          | ref        | ehvp_mess_contim_ix,ehvp_mess_con_ix                                             | ehvp_mess_contim_ix                               | 8       | moodle.mcm.conversationid                    | 1       | Using index                                  |
|    2 | LATERAL DERIVED | <derived3> | ref        | key0                                                                             | key0                                              | 17      | moodle.m.conversationid,moodle.m.timecreated | 2       |                                              |
|    3 | DERIVED         | m          | index      | ehvp_mess_contim_ix,ehvp_mess_con_ix                                             | ehvp_mess_contim_ix                               | 16      | NULL                                         | 5005    | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    3 | DERIVED         | mua        | ref        | ehvp_messuseracti_usemesac_uix,ehvp_messuseracti_use_ix,ehvp_messuseracti_mes_ix | ehvp_messuseracti_mes_ix                          | 8       | moodle.m.id                                  | 1       | Using where; Not exists                      |
|    3 | DERIVED         | mcm        | ref|filter | ehvp_messconvmemb_con_ix,ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix                                | ehvp_messconvmemb_con_ix|ehvp_messconvmemb_use_ix | 8|8     | moodle.m.conversationid                      | 1 (3%)  | Using where; Using rowid filter              |
+------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+

Looks like there are little differences bettween indexes for both servers.
EDIT 3: Those are the returns for the command SHOW CREATE TABLE for the tables involved on the query from the slowlog:
Create tables for server mariadb 11.2.4 (the one with performance issues)
https://pastebin.com/LFTyXvcJ
Create tables for server mariadb 10.4.2 (the one without issues)
https://pastebin.com/FSvj9fCV

you may want to check if the indexes are set and properly set (it is more complex than just adding indexes on things: only add them on the appropriate things, which depends on the type of queries you do!)

some good videos to view about indexes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYh6LrSIDvY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HubezKbFL7E

(the 2nd video especially, but the first one introduces basics)

Thanks! i will take a look

I was able to make the mariadb 11.2.4 server run a little better by FLUSHING all tables, INDEX_STATISTICS, QUERY CACHE, TABLE_STATISTICS and RESET QUERY CACHE on the database,  then adding query cache to my.cnf file:
query_cache_size=64M
it stills runs very slow for the first time but then it loads far more faster afterwards, still i'm still trying to figure out why the message query still has problems however now it has a paliative solution.
I solved the problem!
It turns out the problem was a column conflict on the message tables for moodle, back in june i truncate the table ehvp_messages to clean the messages on moodle, this create a conflict on other tables that register information about those messages because it started creating duplicates on those tables, to solve this i simply truncate all message tables on moodle, run this query on you database (It will delete all messages from your moodle):
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_airnotifier_devices;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_contact_requests;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_contacts;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_conversation_actions;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_conversation_members;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_conversations;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_email_messages;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_popup;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_popup_notifications;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_processors;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_providers;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_read;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_user_actions;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_message_users_blocked;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_messageinbound_datakeys;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_messageinbound_handlers;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_messageinbound_messagelist;
 TRUNCATE TABLE ehvp_messages;


"Analyze didn't work" -- You mean that it did not help with performance? Or that it crashed in some way?  (ANALYZE TABLE is generally useless for InnoDB tables.)
"471 tables" for Moodle?? I would expect no more than a dozen -- 1 for the data and a few for logins.
"[--] Up for: 13s (529 q [40.692 qps]" -- wait at least an hour. Lots of things need to get cached in RAM for the speed to improve
"[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/529)" -- lower long_query_time to "1" and collect the slowlog.
"[--] Physical Memory : 4.0G" and "[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.0G / 1.2G" -- That is dangerously high; is there any swapping?  (I recommend only 1G for innodb_buffer_pool_size on a 4GB RAM machine.)
I assume you cannot modify the queries?  The one you presented is quite complex:

OR is hard to optimize
ORDER BY expression LIMIT ... smells like pagination that cannot be made efficient.
Maybe some composite indexes could be added.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE for the tables.


"You mean that it did not help with performance? Or that it crashed in some way?"
it didn't help with performance
"wait at least an hour. Lots of things need to get cached in RAM for the speed to improve"
Got it, then i will edit the question with the slowlog
"I recommend only 1G for innodb_buffer_pool_size on a 4GB RAM machine."
Got it.

I added a little.

This is the query moodle use to load messages from the message plugin. i will run the command and look for the structure of the tables involved on the query.

Added the return for the commands
